# Using yodlee with php and nusaop library

Tags: php, wsdl, nusoap

With the soap server (“https://sdkeval2.yodlee.com/yodsoap/service”). We are getting below error:
HTTP Error: Couldn't open socket connection to server (http://XX.XX.XX:8080/yodsoap/services/CobrandLoginService/), Error (110): Connection timed out

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be due to the firewall at either end. At your end do check if the outbound traffic is allowed to the specific server on the specified port. At Yodlee's end they use white-list mechanism to filter traffic so make sure your IP addresses are included in the white-list. Note that Yodlee may take up to a week before your IP maybe allowed into their system. If all of these are in order then your connection should be successful without any issue.